# Jmeter HTTP Connects and disconnects

Tags: http, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, session-reuse

I am using random variable to generate port numbers and used the variable in the port field of HTTP Sampler. I have tried to replace this with a counter variable also. Range is around 300 ports.
I need to send traffic to 300 ports but when i send load I see that Jmeter is creating 10x connections for each port and continuosly connecting and disconnecting.

```
 Connection received for HTTPSERVER E-16002-EP, Remote IP Address 10.13.194.52, Remote Port 46486
Disconnect received for HTTPSERVER E-16002-EP, Remote IP Address 10.13.194.52, Remote Port 59720, Bytes sent 3694, Bytes rcvd 5384, Msgs sent 2, Msgs rcvd 2, Up 0d 0h 1m 11.078s.
```

**How do I make Jmeter reuse thread connections and not reconnect after the transaction is complete.**
Keep-alive is on and below settings are also set

```
httpclient4.idletimeout=70000
httpclient4.validate_after_inactivity=66000
httpclient4.time_to_live=70000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property `httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration` to reuse the http connection.

Set following in your `{JMTER_HOME}/bin/user.properties` and restart the JMeter.

```
httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=false
```

By default the value is set to
`httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=true` in the jmeter.properties

Comment: Janesh, interestingly I have enabled this and still facing the disconnects. Below are the settings already set for SSL. https.sessioncontext.shared=true
https.use.cached.ssl.context=true
httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=false

Comment: Zack, Let me check as time permits and check the issue. The Jmeter documentation should have sufficient instructions. You may refer to it meantime

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full control of what's going on under the hood:

- either consider switching to the [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/#HTTP-Raw-Request) sampler
- or create the [HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/) yourself using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/sending-http-and-https-requests-using-groovy-in-jmeter)

Comment: adding timeouts in the HTTP advanced tab finally helped.